# Leaflet and React (Map container not found) On Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I have a React and Leaflet.js component...

```
export const MapSetLocationComponent = (props) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let marker = null
    let map = null
    var container = L.DomUtil.get('setLocationMap')
    if (container != null) {
      container._leaflet_id = null
    }

    map = L.map('setLocationMap', {
      center: [51.4556852, -0.9904706],
      zoom: 16,
      layers: [L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {})]
    })

    map.on('click', function (e) {
      if (marker) map.removeLayer(marker)
      marker = L.marker([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng], { title: 'My marker' }).addTo(map)
    })
  })

  return (
    <>
      <h3>Place your pin</h3>
      <div
        id="setLocationMap"
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          height: '300px'
        }}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

Sometimes when I load the parent component I get the following error

'Map container not found.'

Which would indicate that the  is somehow not available, because if I comment out that div I get the same error.

Anybody got any ideas? Do I need to use a different hook?

Comment: Have you tried short-circuiting your effect hook if your check `if (container != null)` fails?  It shouldn't be necessary, but that would ensure the element is in the dom.

Comment: why not using `[]` inside useEffect as dependency array? On every rerender map is reinstantiated and all the logic you have inside the effect is reexecuted.

Comment: You might want to look at [React Leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you should use the [`useRef` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to access the actual DOM element (once it is available) and pass it to Leaflet `L.map` factory.

```
function myComponent(props) {
  const mapRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapRef && mapRef.current) {
      L.map(mapRef.current); // ref.current is the actual DOM element
    }
  }, [mapRef]); // re-evaluate once the ref is available

  render (<div ref={mapRef} />)
}
```

That is how [React Leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/), mentionned by @pilchard, works under the hood (simplified).

As pointed out by @MattMorgan, your rendered template may not be inserted in the actual DOM tree initially, hence your DOM query may fail. As a general rule, refrain from directly fiddling with DOM that React is supposed to manage.