# React project Error: Map container not found

Tags: reactjs, typescript, leaflet

I have a ts project written with React, I want to render a simple map an a rightsider but I got an error report "Error: Map container not found."Below is my method:

```
 public makemap() {

const map = L.map('map').setView([39.74739, -105], 13);
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: "",
  id: 'mapbox.light'
}).addTo(map);

return (
  <>
    <div id='map' style={{height: '20px',width:'60px'}}/>
  </>
)
```

}

and this is my called of it :

```
<div className="main_container_rightsider_body_list">
          <span className="span">Location: </span><br />
              {this.makemap()}
        </div >
```

what should I do?
btw,I've tried `usEffect()`,but it did not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught Error: Map container is already initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71809240/uncaught-error-map-container-is-already-initialized)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65760773/leaflet-and-react-map-container-not-found-on-render/65768236#65768236 => useRef

Comment: BTW do you use class-based or functional React components?

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same error, tried to do it as given [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/use-mapbox-gl-js-with-react/)

And it worked!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32237145)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Hope it could help.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import icon from "leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png";
import iconShadow from "leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png";

let DefaultIcon = L.icon({
iconUrl: icon,
shadowUrl: iconShadow,
});

export default function Map() {
useEffect(() => {
    var container = L.DomUtil.get("map");

    if (container != null) {
    container._leaflet_id = null;
    }
    var map = L.map("map").setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    L.tileLayer(
    "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}",
    {
        attribution:
        'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: "mapbox/streets-v11",
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        accessToken:
        "your.mapbox.access.token",
    }
    ).addTo(map);
    L.Marker.prototype.options.icon = DefaultIcon;
    var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
    marker.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup.").openPopup();
}, []);
return <div id="map" style={{ height: "100vh" }}></div>;
}
```

Don't forget to insert these CSS and JS to your index.html head:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-hoalWLoI8r4UszCkZ5kL8vayOGVae1oxXe/2A4AO6J9+580uKHDO3JdHb7NzwwzK5xr/Fs0W40kiNHxM9vyTtQ==" crossorigin=""/>`

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-BB3hKbKWOc9Ez/TAwyWxNXeoV9c1v6FIeYiBieIWkpLjauysF18NzgR1MBNBXf8/KABdlkX68nAhlwcDFLGPCQ==" crossorigin=""></script>`